# IIS7 problem with IIS_IUSRS permission. Cannot play a mp3 file

Tags: iis-7, permissions

I have an asp.net application on IIS 7 and Windows Server 2008. I have a folder where the administrator can upload mp3s through a asp.net form. The folder that the mp3s are stored has permissions under IIS_IUSRS (IIS USERS) to write, read, etc. When he upload a file, automatically the new file loses all the permissions and consequently this mp3 cannot be played by the website either from an authenticated user nor from an anonymous user. If I change the permissions manually the problem is fixed, but it starts again in a new uploading. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Either the upload script is changing the permissions when it saves the file, or the NTFS permissions aren't setting to inherit the permissions correctly.

To rule out (or in) the upload script, try dropping a file in that folder manually (copy, not move) and make sure that it obtains the correct permissions.  If it does, then the issue is most likely with the asp.net form.

If the issue happens manually from Windows Explorer too, then check the Advanced NTFS permissions.  It's possible that the permissions for the IIS_IUSERS user are set for 'this folder only' and aren't inheriting for new files.

Comment: I want to thank you for your answer. I tried your test (copy a file and check what were the permissions) and there wasn't any problem with copy the file manually. However, the same technique I used to upload files with other sites and this does not happen in any other site. I noticed that it does not only lose the permissions for the IIS_IUSERS but it reports fewer users in the permission list. The manual copy reported these users "SYSTEM
NETWORK SERVICE
Administrators
Users
IIS_IUSRS
TrustedInstaller" and the uploading reported these "SYSTEM
NETWORK SERVICE
Administrators
IIS_IUSRS".

Comment: Based on your findings, it sounds like the asp.net form updates the permissions when it saves the file.  I would review that form if you have access to the source and see what it's attempting to do.